# Load WSDL by environment in .NET Web API project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, soap, wsdl

I have different WSDL URLs for development and production. Whenever I add WSDL web reference in my ASP.NET 7.0 Web API application, it generates `ConnectedService.json` and `Reference.cs` files.

Both these files contain the WSDL URL, and I need to dynamically pick the URL from `appsettings.json` based on the environment.

File: `Reference.cs` - URL included like:

```
private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
{
    if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.UMarketSC))
    {
        return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/services/umarketsc");
    }

    throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
}
```

File: `ConnectedService.json`

URL included like:

```
"ExtendedData": {
    "inputs": [
        "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/services/umarketsc?wsdl"
    ],
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is service's constructor which takes `EndpointAddress` (or `Binding`) for the service ... use it instead parameterless one

Comment: @Slevin, yes there is a constructor, and it works now. Thanks